# Request query with empty models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models (Collections and Interests) with 2 link tables (Collectionning and Interesting).
I would like to select all the collections where the interest targeted is not.

But with my actual query, it doesn't select the empty collections:

```
Collection.joins("LEFT JOIN `interestings` ON `interestings`.`collection_id` = `collections`.`id` LEFT JOIN `interests` ON `interests`.`id` = `interestings`.`interest_id`").where.not(interests: {id: 1}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected /but I haven't tested ;)/

```
Collection.where('id not in ?', Interesting.where(interest_id: 1).pluck(:collection_id))
```

I'm not sure about limits for a "not in" list, but if your tables are too big for this you can avoid passing data via Ruby array and use pure SQL:

```
Collection.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM collections WHERE collection_id NOT IN (SELECT collection_id FROM interestings WHERE interest_id = 1)')
```